# Html.RenderAction does not work on translated route

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4.

I implemented the solution [here](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2010/01/26/Translating-routes-%28ASPNET-MVC-and-Webforms%29.aspx), and it works great for Html.ActionLink. However, when I use Html.Action or Html.RenderAction it doesn't work. I get error:

***The controller for path '/Demarrer' was not found or does not implement IController.***

Steps to reproduce:

1. Download the sample code from the website above. [LocalizedRouteExample.zip](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/file.axd?file=2009/12/LocalizedRouteExample.zip) (23.23 kb)
2. Add a new controller **SetupController** and respective View.
3. Add on the homepage:

> `<%= Html.ActionLink("Setup", "Index", "Setup") %>`
>
> `<% Html.RenderAction("Index", "Setup"); %>`

.
 4. Add on Global.asax line 30:

> `new RouteValueTranslation(cultureFR, "Setup", "Installation")`

.

> ```
> public class SetupController : Controller
> {
>     public ActionResult Index()
>     {
>         return PartialView();
>     }
> }
> ```

Views/Setup/Index.ascx:

> ```
> <%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>
> <strong>This is SETUP</strong>
> ```

5) Now change to French language and jump back to homepage.

I know its' because it can't find the controller. What should I pass to this RenderAction method to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

For RenderAction, a solution using "ViewContext.RequestContext.RouteData.DataTokens" is presented here:

[ASP.NET (MVC) routes internationalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221561/asp-net-mvc-routes-internationalization)